# Security problems of world-writable batch files in Windows program folder

Tags: windows, security, batch-file

I have a little problem. Usually I am a Linux developer, but currently I have to develop for Windows 7 & 8. Generally not a problem, but clearly I lack some serious experience on this platform. My problem: My marketing guy wants to force me to add a world-writable batch file in our program's installation folder. Under Linux a horrible idea. Probably not a better idea under Windows. But what exactly are the risks here? I need some good arguments against it. Or... much unlikely.. a 'No problem at all, go ahead'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much exactly what you'd expect.  If your application calls that batch file, then any user can put commands in it to be run with the privileges of the user running your application.

If your application acquires administrative permissions prior to running that batch file, then it's more or less like letting any user use your application to execute commands as root.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I expected. But as a Windows noob I wanted to make sure before I start the fight.